# How to create custom flutter sdk widget, rebuild flutter and use new widget

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to figure out how to build a custom flutter sdk with a widget that I added.

background: I realized that the PaginatedDataTable requires a header (per this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/38604) and I'd like to update that widget to make it optional.

Github user wolfcro1984 has a pull request to do the same thing here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/26352/files
and I'd like to use that code in my current flutter version.  However, I'm not sure how to actually build flutter again after that change so that I can use that widget.

How do you build the flutter sdk in order to make a custom flutter version?  Is there documentation out there somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to copy the code in your own dart file and do the modification.  You can go to paginated_data_table.dart, grab all the code and put it in your own .dart file.

How to remove the header :

1. Go to paginated_data_table.dart (equivalent)
2. Remove @required before 'header' parameter.
3. Remove `assert(header != null)`
4. Go to Widget build method and remove Semantics. This is under CARD section in comments.

I took a sample from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54386348/1367159), did the modification and the result is :

[image]

The edits I made are [here](https://pastebin.com/ZNPSaxHa).

*Note : You'll need to change the import part when you copy the standard code in your custom widget.*

Comment: also, it should be noted that the code as it's written won't work in your own dart file.  The imports for "import 'button_bar.dart';   import 'card.dart';  , etc   can all be replaced with "import 'package:flutter/material.dart';"  (just in case someone else stumbles in here in the future.)