# Remove empty rows from Flutter paginated datatable

Tags: datatables, setstate, flutter-row, paginateddatatable

[image]

I tried to remove empty rows per page using this reference [remove empty rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54376593/flutter-paginateddatatable-rowsperpage).

It removes empty rows on page changes but when I try to remove rows on click using this code:

```
datasList.remove(datasList[index]);
notifyListeners();
```

I want to update the state using:

```
setState(() {

});
```

of parent class but it shows error.

It removes data but not is removing row from table.

Answer (score 0):

try this one :
onPageChanged: (n) {

```
                      if (valueResponse.length - n < rowsPerPage) {
                       setState(() {
                        rowsPerPage = tableSource.rowCount - n;
```

});
}

```
                  },
```